# Displaying custom test results in Jenkins Maven job

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I just added some Python unit tests to an existing Maven POM but I can't seem to get Jenkins to report the results of the tests when it runs the build.

I'm running [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) tests from Maven with the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) during the "test" phase. The tests run successfully from the Jenkins job and generate an xUnit compatible test report to *target/surefire-reports/TEST-nosetests.xml*, but Jenkins doesn't pick up on the results.

Interestingly, Maven also reports no tests run before executing the test suite:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:exec (nosetests) @ server ---
[INFO] ................
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Ran 16 tests in 194.799s
[INFO] 
[INFO] OK
[INFO] Registering compile source root /Volumes/Data/workspace/myProject/target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So is this a problem with Jenkins not seeing the results, or with Maven not treating my test suite as actual tests?

Comment: I am almost 9 years too late but if someone sees this issue "there are no tests to run" in the Java world this can be a result of test classes not having the word Test at the Start or End of test. Atleast that is one reason, when you can see this log when trying to run from Maven. Another reason can be not tagging the tests as @Test (but in that case, you will not be able to run from your IDE itself). So that is less likely. So hopefully if somone lands here with this error (using java and maven, this may be useful for them).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I worked through this problem by using a "free-style software project" in Jenkins rather than the "maven2/3" project.

[image: New Project]

Under **Build**, choose **Add build step** and configure the project to **Invoke top-level Maven targets**. I'm using the *test* target.

[image: Invoke top-level Maven targets]

Finally, under **Post-build Actions** choose **Add post-build action** of **Publish JUnit test result report** and point it at the xUnit output from your tests. This option is not available for Maven 2/3 jobs for some reason.

[image: Publish JUnit test result report]

Comment: I think is related to JENKINS-9980 bug. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9980

Answer (score 4):

To build upon the answer by [bpanulla](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13612767/2807423), if you have tests in more than one sub-directory of your project, you can use a wildcard in the "Test report XMLs" field, such as: `**/target/surefire-reports/*.xml`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a more modular Jenkins setup using a free project will not correctly build submodules. If the maven-plugin that generates the reports execution id is `e2eTests`, then add the following snippet to your pom.xml and the jenkins maven plugin will take care of the rest!

```
<properties>
    <jenkins.e2eTests.reportsDirectory>target/protractor-reports</jenkins.e2eTests.reportsDirectory>
</properties>
```

See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+maven2+project

Answer (score 1):

Try after adding the maven compiler plugin

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                <testSource>1.8</testSource>
                <testTarget>1.8</testTarget>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in the Tests run output that Maven didn't recognized the tests as tests. Furthermore to see the results in Jenkins you need to check if nope can create junit compatible output result files (which i assume) which can be read by jenkins and of course displayed.

Comment: Nose can generate compatible output, as I stated in the question. The problem is that I couldn't get Maven to see the output to report it to Jenkins. My own answer shows how to get around Maven and get Jenkins to see the report directly.